# VBA Like operator / Regular Expressions

Tags: excel, regex, vba

In VBA, what's the regular expressions that matches each of following strings: `56-...` and `...-28`?

For the second one I tried the following but to no avail:

```
Target.Value Like "[\.]{3}[\-]{1}[0-9]{1,}"
```

Comment: Try `If Target.Value Like "56-...*" And Target.Value Like "*...-28" Then` or  `If Target.Value Like "##-...*" And Target.Value Like "*...-##" Then` if you mean *"begins with"* and *"ends with"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using VBA "regex" like normal regex. That won't work: the like operator in VBA takes expressions that are different from regex and very limited compared to them. Here is the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator).

FYI, the operand that would match your 2nd string is `"...-##"` (3 dots, 1 hyphen, 2 digits); this is as you can see very different from a regex.
To exclude numbers that have leading zeroes, you can use `"...-[1-9]#"` (3 dots,1 hyphen, 1 digit except 0 then annother digit).
Note that the above expressions behave similarly to regular expression with start/end of string anchors (`^` and `$`). To be a perfect match of the expression you have provided, it needs to be surrounded by `*`.

Using regular expressions in VBA can be done by adding a reference (menu Tools) to `Microsoft VBScripts Regular expressions 5.5`.
For the case in your question, that seems overkill and introduces a lot of additional code.
Instead, simply do:

```vb
Target.Value Like "*#-...*" OR Target.Value Like "*...-#*"
'Or
Target.Value Like "*[1-9]#-...*" OR Target.Value Like "*...-[1-9]#*"
```

Edit:
`Like` is severly limited compared to regex.

If what you wanted was test your string with start/end anchors, you can do it although it requires you to be smart:

```vb
Target.Value Like "[1-9]" & String(Len(Target.Value) - 5, "#") & "-..." Or _
Target.Value Like "...-[1-9]" & String(Len(Target.Value) - 5, "#")
'Or
Target.Value Like String(Len(Target.Value) - 4, "#") & "-..." Or _
Target.Value Like "...-" & String(Len(Target.Value) - 4, "#")
```

Anything more complex than the above cases requires proper regex.

Answer (score 1):

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()
    Dim sTxt As String, oMatch As Object
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "\d+-\.{3}"
        sTxt = "the frist one 56-..."
        For Each oMatch In .Execute(sTxt)
            Debug.Print oMatch.Value
        Next
        .Pattern = "\.{3}-\d+"
        sTxt = "For the second one...-28"
        For Each oMatch In .Execute(sTxt)
            Debug.Print oMatch.Value
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

***Output:***

```
56-...
...-28
```